# Setting a Kubernetes node as unavailable

Tags: kubernetes

Can any one please tell the options on how to set a Kubernetes node unavailable and reschedule
all the pods running on it.

I have tried draining the node, but I am not sure if draining a node actually reschedule the pods running on it to some other node or not?

By using --force option, my only existing pod was evicted/deleted.

Comment: Please format your post to be clear and understandable.  Format text.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using Kubernetes 1.5+, `kubectl drain <nodename>` should do the trick. (See here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/)

Maybe there was no node left, that could start your Pod? This does not mean, that there is no node left, but maybe the scheduler wasn't able to reschedule your Pod on another node.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/#use-kubectl-drain-to-remove-a-node-from-service) draining will reschedule existing pods to other nodes and mark the node as not scheduleable using a `NoSchedule` taint so that no new pods will be scheduled on that node.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kubernetes deployments/ReplicaSets  they should do this for you. Your deployment is configured with a set number of replicas to create for each pod when you remove a node the scheduler will see that the current active number is less than the desired number and automatically  create new ones.

If you are just deploying pods without a deployment, then this won't happen and the only solution is manually redeploying - that is why you should use deployment.

**NOTE:**

When you are running new pods, you are not moving the previously running pods. Every state previous pods has that is not persisted will be gone.

Take a look: [rescheduling-pods-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201501/how-to-reschedule-my-pods-after-scaling-down-a-node-in-azure-kubernetes-service).

However using command `$ kubectl drain` is also good idea:

Look at the answer - [draining-nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861796/what-happens-when-you-drain-nodes-in-a-kubernetes-cluster).

From official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#drain):

> The 'drain' evicts or deletes all pods except mirror
> pods (which cannot be deleted through the API server).
> If there are DaemonSet-managed pods, drain will not proceed
> without --ignore-daemonsets, and regardless it will not
> delete any DaemonSet-managed pods, because those pods would
> be immediately replaced by the DaemonSet controller, which ignores unschedulable markings. If there are any pods
> that are neither mirror pods nor managed by ReplicationController,
> ReplicaSet, DaemonSet, StatefulSet or Job, then drain
> will not delete any pods
> unless you use --force. --force will also allow deletion
> to proceed if the managing resource of one or more
> pods is missing.

You can use   [chart](https://kubernetes.io/images/docs/kubectl_drain.svg) which will illustrate what happens when you will use  `$ kubectl drain` command.

Try also to use  `$ kubectl drain`  with  `--dry-run`  argument so you can see its outcome before any changes are applied:

```
$ kubectl drain <node-name> --force --dry-run
```

**NOTE:** It will not show any errors about existing local data or daemonsets which you can see without using  `--dry-run` argument.